# SQL - Converting String to Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to convert a value to a SQL Server `DateTime`.

Data looks like below :

- 20161021-12:55:16.000
- 20161021-13:22:09.974

I tried

```
CONVERT(DATE, '20161021-12:55:16.000', 102)
```

and it throws an error.

Can I get help in SQL to convert these samples into a valid date time?

Also these values are in UTC.

I need to convert them to EST.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Wrong format number. Look at the list [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're confident with your format being consistent then you can just take that dash out (I've used datetime for illustration purposes);

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' '), 102)
```

Result

```
2016-10-21 12:55:16.000
```

For the conversion you can convert to datetime, take off your hours and then convert to the date format you want;

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(hh,-5,CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' '))), 102)
```

Result;

```
2016-10-21 07:55:16.000
```

To get a better idea of this, set it before 5am and you will get the previous day;

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(hh,-5,CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('20161021-04:55:16.000','-',' '))), 102)
```

Result

```
2016-10-20 23:55:16.000
```

For reference, on my test systems you don't need to convert to 102, that's the default.

```
DATEADD(hh,-5,CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('20161021-04:55:16.000','-',' ')))
```

To get the time difference dynamically do something like this;

```
DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()),CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('20161021-04:55:16.000','-',' ')))
```

Comment: Depending on Day Light Savings Time it will be 4 or 5 hours.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti good point, I've updated the answer to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

No need for the CONVERT 102.

```
Select cast(replace('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' ') as datetime)
```

Returns

```
2016-10-21 12:55:16.000
```

To Convert From UTC to Local Server.  One should keep in mind that the time difference will change with **Daylight Savings Time** (EDT/EST)

```
Select DateAdd(MINUTE,DateDiff(MINUTE,GetUTCDate(),GetDate()),cast(replace('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' ') as datetime))
```

Reuturns

```
2016-10-21 07:55:16.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, replace('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' '), 102)
```

For EST

```
select dateadd(HH,-5,CONVERT(DATETIME, replace('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' '), 102))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                REPLACE('20161021-12:55:16.000','-',' ')), 
                        DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) 
   AS ColumnInLocalTime
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from explanation on what you are doing beyond the other answers.